# Could not find imported module support code for freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipaclient_test

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook, freeipa

My ansible controller is running on a Rocky 8.5 machine with the ansible-freeipa version 0.3.8-1.el8 rpm package installed.

```
ansible 2.9.27
config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
python version = 3.6.8 (default, Nov 9 2021, 14:44:26) [GCC 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-3)]
```

I have the ansible_freeipa collection stored under /etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa.

I've updated my ansible.cfg "collections" parameter to point to: /etc/ansible/community_collections.

I'm attempting to join three hosts to a freshly installed freeipa server. When I run my playbook it starts to apply the ipaclient role but fails at the "Install - IPA client test" task which is found in the ipaclient/tasks/install.yml file.

It appears to be failing to find the "ansible_ipa_client.py" file. But I can see that it's located in /etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/module_utils

Here's what happens when I run the play:

```
ansible-playbook 2.9.27
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Nov  9 2021, 14:44:26) [GCC 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-3)]
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
Skipping callback 'actionable', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'counter_enabled', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'debug', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'dense', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'dense', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'full_skip', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'json', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'minimal', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'null', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'oneline', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'selective', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'skippy', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'stderr', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'unixy', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'yaml', as we already have a stdout callback.

PLAYBOOK: bootstrap.yml ********************************************************************************************************************
1 plays in bootstrap.yml

PLAY [ipaclients] **************************************************************************************************************************
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers
Thursday 28 April 2022  19:48:20 +0000 (0:00:00.233)       0:00:00.233 ******** 
Thursday 28 April 2022  19:48:20 +0000 (0:00:00.023)       0:00:00.256 ******** 
Thursday 28 April 2022  19:48:20 +0000 (0:00:00.050)       0:00:00.306 ******** 

TASK [freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipaclient : Import variables specific to distribution] *******************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/tasks/main.yml:4
ok: [cm.mts.sys] => (item=/etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/vars/RedHat-8.yml) => {"ansible_facts": {"ipaclient_packages": ["@idm:DL1/client"]}, "ansible_included_var_files": ["/etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/vars/RedHat-8.yml"], "ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "/etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/vars/RedHat-8.yml"}
Thursday 28 April 2022  19:48:20 +0000 (0:00:00.164)       0:00:00.471 ******** 
ok: [inf-4.mts.sys] => (item=/etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/vars/RedHat-8.yml) => {"ansible_facts": {"ipaclient_packages": ["@idm:DL1/client"]}, "ansible_included_var_files": ["/etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/vars/RedHat-8.yml"], "ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "/etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/vars/RedHat-8.yml"}
Thursday 28 April 2022  19:48:20 +0000 (0:00:00.059)       0:00:00.531 ******** 
ok: [mitts-hst-5.mts.sys] => (item=/etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/vars/RedHat-8.yml) => {"ansible_facts": {"ipaclient_packages": ["@idm:DL1/client"]}, "ansible_included_var_files": ["/etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/vars/RedHat-8.yml"], "ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "/etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/vars/RedHat-8.yml"}
Thursday 28 April 2022  19:48:20 +0000 (0:00:00.108)       0:00:00.639 ******** 
included: /etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/tasks/install.yml for cm.mts.sys
Thursday 28 April 2022  19:48:21 +0000 (0:00:00.155)       0:00:00.795 ******** 
included: /etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/tasks/install.yml for inf-4.mts.sys, mitts-hst-5.mts.sys
Thursday 28 April 2022  19:48:21 +0000 (0:00:00.118)       0:00:00.914 ******** 
Thursday 28 April 2022  19:48:21 +0000 (0:00:00.048)       0:00:00.962 ******** 

TASK [freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipaclient : Install - Ensure that IPA client packages are installed] *****************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/tasks/install.yml:4
ok: [cm.mts.sys] => {"changed": false, "msg": "Nothing to do", "rc": 0, "results": []}
Thursday 28 April 2022  19:48:23 +0000 (0:00:02.024)       0:00:02.987 ******** 

TASK [freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipaclient : Install - Ensure that IPA client packages are installed] *****************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/tasks/install.yml:4
ok: [inf-4.mts.sys] => {"changed": false, "msg": "Nothing to do", "rc": 0, "results": []}
Thursday 28 April 2022  19:48:23 +0000 (0:00:00.025)       0:00:03.013 ******** 

TASK [freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipaclient : Install - Set ipaclient_servers] *****************************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/tasks/install.yml:10
skipping: [cm.mts.sys] => {"changed": false, "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"}
Thursday 28 April 2022  19:48:23 +0000 (0:00:00.136)       0:00:03.150 ******** 

TASK [freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipaclient : Install - Set ipaclient_servers] *****************************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/tasks/install.yml:10
skipping: [inf-4.mts.sys] => {"changed": false, "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"}
Thursday 28 April 2022  19:48:23 +0000 (0:00:00.053)       0:00:03.204 ******** 

TASK [freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipaclient : Install - Set ipaclient_servers from cluster inventory] ******************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/tasks/install.yml:15
skipping: [cm.mts.sys] => {"changed": false, "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"}
Thursday 28 April 2022  19:48:23 +0000 (0:00:00.135)       0:00:03.339 ******** 

TASK [freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipaclient : Install - Set ipaclient_servers from cluster inventory] ******************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/tasks/install.yml:15
skipping: [inf-4.mts.sys] => {"changed": false, "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"}
Thursday 28 April 2022  19:48:23 +0000 (0:00:00.052)       0:00:03.392 ******** 

TASK [freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipaclient : Install - Check that either principal or keytab is set] ******************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/tasks/install.yml:21
skipping: [cm.mts.sys] => {"changed": false, "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"}
Thursday 28 April 2022  19:48:23 +0000 (0:00:00.078)       0:00:03.471 ******** 

TASK [freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipaclient : Install - Check that either principal or keytab is set] ******************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/tasks/install.yml:21
skipping: [inf-4.mts.sys] => {"changed": false, "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"}
Thursday 28 April 2022  19:48:23 +0000 (0:00:00.089)       0:00:03.560 ******** 

TASK [freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipaclient : Install - Set default principal if no keytab is given] *******************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/tasks/install.yml:25
skipping: [cm.mts.sys] => {"changed": false, "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"}
Thursday 28 April 2022  19:48:23 +0000 (0:00:00.090)       0:00:03.651 ******** 

TASK [freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipaclient : Install - Set default principal if no keytab is given] *******************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/tasks/install.yml:25
skipping: [inf-4.mts.sys] => {"changed": false, "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"}
Thursday 28 April 2022  19:48:23 +0000 (0:00:00.080)       0:00:03.732 ******** 

TASK [freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipaclient : Install - IPA client test] ***********************************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/tasks/install.yml:30
fatal: [cm.mts.sys]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Could not find imported module support code for freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipaclient_test.  Looked for either validate_domain_name.py or ansible_ipa_client.py"}

TASK [freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipaclient : Install - IPA client test] ***********************************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/tasks/install.yml:30
fatal: [inf-4.mts.sys]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Could not find imported module support code for freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipaclient_test.  Looked for either validate_domain_name.py or ansible_ipa_client.py"}

TASK [freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipaclient : Install - Ensure that IPA client packages are installed] *****************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/tasks/install.yml:4
ok: [mitts-hst-5.mts.sys] => {"changed": false, "msg": "Nothing to do", "rc": 0, "results": []}
Thursday 28 April 2022  19:48:24 +0000 (0:00:00.860)       0:00:04.592 ******** 

TASK [freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipaclient : Install - Set ipaclient_servers] *****************************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/tasks/install.yml:10
skipping: [mitts-hst-5.mts.sys] => {"changed": false, "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"}
Thursday 28 April 2022  19:48:25 +0000 (0:00:00.222)       0:00:04.814 ******** 

TASK [freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipaclient : Install - Set ipaclient_servers from cluster inventory] ******************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/tasks/install.yml:15
skipping: [mitts-hst-5.mts.sys] => {"changed": false, "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"}
Thursday 28 April 2022  19:48:25 +0000 (0:00:00.220)       0:00:05.035 ******** 

TASK [freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipaclient : Install - Check that either principal or keytab is set] ******************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/tasks/install.yml:21
skipping: [mitts-hst-5.mts.sys] => {"changed": false, "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"}
Thursday 28 April 2022  19:48:25 +0000 (0:00:00.208)       0:00:05.244 ******** 

TASK [freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipaclient : Install - Set default principal if no keytab is given] *******************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/tasks/install.yml:25
skipping: [mitts-hst-5.mts.sys] => {"changed": false, "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"}
Thursday 28 April 2022  19:48:25 +0000 (0:00:00.213)       0:00:05.457 ******** 

TASK [freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipaclient : Install - IPA client test] ***********************************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/tasks/install.yml:30
fatal: [mitts-hst-5.mts.sys]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Could not find imported module support code for freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipaclient_test.  Looked for either validate_domain_name.py or ansible_ipa_client.py"}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************
cm.mts.sys                 : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=4    rescued=0    ignored=0   
inf-4.mts.sys              : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=4    rescued=0    ignored=0   
mitts-hst-5.mts.sys        : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=4    rescued=0    ignored=0   

Thursday 28 April 2022  19:48:25 +0000 (0:00:00.211)       0:00:05.669 ******** 
=============================================================================== 
freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipaclient : Install - Ensure that IPA client packages are installed ----------------------------------------- 2.02s
/etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/tasks/install.yml:4 ------------------------
freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipaclient : Install - Set ipaclient_servers ----------------------------------------------------------------- 0.22s
/etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/tasks/install.yml:10 -----------------------
freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipaclient : Install - Set ipaclient_servers from cluster inventory ------------------------------------------ 0.22s
/etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/tasks/install.yml:15 -----------------------
freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipaclient : Install - Set default principal if no keytab is given ------------------------------------------- 0.21s
/etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/tasks/install.yml:25 -----------------------
freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipaclient : Install - IPA client test ----------------------------------------------------------------------- 0.21s
/etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/tasks/install.yml:30 -----------------------
freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipaclient : Install - Check that either principal or keytab is set ------------------------------------------ 0.21s
/etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/tasks/install.yml:21 -----------------------
freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipaclient : Import variables specific to distribution ------------------------------------------------------- 0.16s
/etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/tasks/main.yml:4 ---------------------------
freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipaclient : Install IPA client ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 0.16s
/etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/tasks/main.yml:19 --------------------------
freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipaclient : Install - Ensure that IPA client packages are installed ----------------------------------------- 0.12s
/etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/tasks/install.yml:4 ------------------------
freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipaclient : Install - Set default principal if no keytab is given ------------------------------------------- 0.09s
/etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/tasks/install.yml:25 -----------------------
freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipaclient : Install - IPA client test ----------------------------------------------------------------------- 0.08s
/etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/tasks/install.yml:30 -----------------------
freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipaclient : Install - Set ipaclient_servers from cluster inventory ------------------------------------------ 0.05s
/etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/tasks/install.yml:15 -----------------------
freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipaclient : Install - Check that either principal or keytab is set ------------------------------------------ 0.05s
/etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/tasks/install.yml:21 -----------------------
freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipaclient : Install - Set ipaclient_servers ----------------------------------------------------------------- 0.03s
/etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections/freeipa/ansible_freeipa/roles/ipaclient/tasks/install.yml:10 -----------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this I had to delete my copy of the ansible_freeipa community collection from /etc/ansible/community_collections/ansible_collections. This is the location I specify in my ansible.cfg where my community collections are located.  Your configuration may be different.  I then had to re-install the community collection by download a fresh copy from ansible galaxy at: https://galaxy.ansible.com/freeipa/ansible_freeipa.

I installed manually by download the tar.gz file from ansible-galaxy.  I then used the following command to install it.

ansible-galaxy collection install -p /etc/ansible/community_collections ~/freeipa-ansible_freeipa-1.8.4.tar.gz